# Is there a silverlight grid with "smart" server-side grouping?

Tags: silverlight

Let's say, I have a big table in my server-side database. For instance, 1 million rows and 50 columns.

I want to use a data grid on my silverlight application to show data from that table.
This data grid should support grouping, and even nested grouping.

For example, if we think from SQL-point of view, this grid should somehow send "GroupBy" to the data table, and for nested grouping it should send "Where" + "GroupBy".
And when a group is expanded, it just should send "Where".
It would be great, if it applies also Take and Skip to the query, because in a worst case I can have 1 million groups.

It's great if this grid can use and change LINQ query is such a way, because then I can write my own IQueryable implementation and detect grouped columns, etc.

But it seems there is no such grids at all :(
Many grids support server-side paging, sorting and filtering.
But is there anybody supporting a good server-side grouping?